# Getting specific value from dict

Tags: python

I have a view for getting a soap response (using suds)

The output I get is formatted like this:

```
('birthdate', None)('updated', datetime.date(2014, 7, 11))('connected_to', Test1,Test2)
```

My view code is like this:

```
def view_webservice(request):


    #Url to WSDL file
    url = 'https://www.domain.com/webservices.nsf/MemberService?WSDL'


    imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
    doctor = ImportDoctor(imp) 


    client = Client(url, username='****', password='****', doctor=doctor)


    user_id='000001'

    result = client.service.readMember(userId=user_id)



    return HttpResponse(result) #Output: ('birthdate', None)('updated', datetime.date(2014, 7, 11))('connected_to', Test1,Test2)
```

I have tried getting a value like this:

`birthdate = result.get('birthdate')` (error: MemberRead instance has no attribute 'get') `birthdate = result('birthdate')` (error: MemberRead instance has no **call** method)

What is the correct way of getting the value?

## Edit:

My traceback of `result` is:

```
(MedlemRead){
   birthdate = None
   updated = 2014-07-11
   connected_to = "Test1,Test2"
 }
```

## Edit 2:

The answer was doing: `result.birthdate`

Comment: If it was a dict, `result['birthdate']` would be the way. However, it appears to be a class called `MemberRead`, and without seeing the code (or even a reference to the library you're using) we have no way of knowing what that actually is.

Comment: Does `result = dict(result)` work? It looks like the object is an iterable (a sequence) of key-value pairs.

Comment: It was as simple as this: `result.birthdate`

Comment: Print out `dir(result`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOAP is Simple **Object** Access Protocol, so the things you get back are objects. That's why the WSDL has such strict definitions of types of values to be sent and what to expect back.

Luckily, `suds` and other SOAP libraries take care of the mundane details for you and return to you a fully animated object of the correct type.

To access any values, you need to treat the response as an object; which means in your case the answer is `result.birthdate`.

Keep in mind that the returned object will have the correct types of data as well. So if you are expecting a custom *nested* object, you'll have to access it correctly.